# "maximum recursion depth exceeded" trying to call an overloaded function

Tags: python, overloading, infinite-recursion

I'm setting up a custom user authentication, and when I try to create a superuser in powershell it gives me an error "  [Previous line repeated 986 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"
which is referring to my create_superuser()

### models.py

```
def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
    user = self.create_superuser(
        username,
        password = password,
        is_staff = True,
        is_admin = True

    )
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Comment: Do not call this function from itself endlessly?

Comment: There it least the class missing in your code, but it looks like `create_superuser()` is calling itself, and then calling itself and so on.

Comment: you are calling `create_superuser` inside `create_superuser` so it loops undefinitely ( recursion error because the program detected it was endless )

Comment: What do you mean by "overloaded function"? Where is the code that you want to be called this way? Is it another method in the same class, or does it belong to a base class, or exactly what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It is I who added "overloaded" to the title so that it's googlable. He calls the function of the same object with the same name but a different signature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to call an overloaded function.

In Python, there's no function overloading. Instead, a function can have a flexible signature ([optional arguments, receiving any arguments via `*args` and `**kwargs`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nrm-aTCwdQ)).
If you define two functions with the same name in the same scope, the one encountered later by the interpreter will simply replace the former.

So, you need to consolidate your two functions into one with a flexible signature. (Nothing prevents you from splitting off helper functions or anything under the hood, but they need to have different names).

Answer (score 0):

## create super user is create user forcing password

```
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """ Manager para perfiles de usuario """
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        """ Crear Nuevo UserProfile """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('username!!!')
        #email= self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=uername)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password): 
        user = self.create_user(username=username, 
                            password = password,
                            is_staff=True,
                            is_admin = True)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: `create_user` should probably accept the `is_staff` and `is_admin` parameters and do something with them.